# How to handle complex non CRUD operations with web API?

Tags: c#, api

How to handle complex non CRUD operations with web API?

For example lets say that we have two methods in repository with complex queries. This are two queries with many joins.

This can be entity framework or ADO.Net - what ever.

Like : **Get all Students with Subjects and their Professors and ...** (and more and more joins)... **where students are older than x and Professors have status y**... (and more and more conditions)

And also there are in same repository other operations that are similar. So we have many non CRUD operations.

In every API I already have CRUD operation like GetStudents (in StudentsController), GetSubjects(in SubjectsController) , GetProfessors(in ProfessorsController)...
And same for 'post','put','delete'.

My main questions are

1. How to design this?
2. Should I create new API controllers for this purpose ?
3. What if I want to have many GetStudents API methods with different
   conditions and joins with different tables

Comment: What do you mean with ""CRUDE"? If you thought about CRUD-operations, the "R" stands for "read". As you want to fetch data, this is reading, so this is CRUD... If you have a database (and I suppose you do), It is no problem to get data of high complexity at any time. Best is to define the queries within the db (user defined functions or VIEWs) and call them from your application.

Comment: Yes sorry, off course CRUD.

Comment: Actually I have no idea what you want... Please give details: Which database (product and version), what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ Shnugo Ok but what if I want to have many GetStudents API methods with different conditions and joined with different tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using a database like SQL Server. Other RDBMS will have similiar features.

Just define an (inline!) UDF with as many parameters you like.

Within this UDF it's on you to implement the correct behaviour: Which parameters may be NULL and what happens with them?

In your application you need one single method taking all needed parameters (define the ones which may be null as nullable types (like `int?`).

All ORM tools (EF also) will provide assistants to get an UDF into your application with all needed methods.

The result is a (typed) DataTable with all columns your UDF provides.

If you need different queries, different joins, really different structure, just define all of them in different UDFs. Anyway you'll have to create them somewhere. This is best do be done within your RDBMS. If it is precompiled it will have better performance, better usage of indexes and statistics...

To be honest: This is absolutely basics... Every data related application is doing exactly this. You'll find tons of examples. But you must sepcify a concrete problem. This is far to broad to give a **solution** as answer.

Comment: @Raskolnikov, yes, but if you want to allow `NULL` your enum should include a value for `undefined` and you'll use something like `int? paramValue = null; if(x!=myEnum.Undefined) paramValue=(int)x;` to cast your enum value (stored in `x`) to the `int?` type. I'd define overwritten methods. The lowest taking "real" types, the higher taking whatever you want, do the casts and call a lower one...